# Lightbox CSS customizing

Tags: css, lightbox

This is the Lightbox CSS sheet:

```
#lightbox{  position: absolute; left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 100; text-align: center; line-height: 0;}
#lightbox img{ width: auto; height: auto;}
#lightbox a img{ border: none; }

#outerImageContainer{ position: relative; background-color: #fff; width: 250px; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto; }
#imageContainer{ padding: 10px; }

#loading{ position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 0%; height: 25%; width: 100%; text-align: center; line-height: 0; }
#hoverNav{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index: 10; }
#imageContainer>#hoverNav{ left: 0;}
#hoverNav a{ outline: none;}

#prevLink, #nextLink{ width: 49%; height: 100%; background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,AAAA); /* Trick IE into showing hover */ display: block; }
#prevLink { left: 0; float: left;}
#nextLink { right: 0; float: right;}
#prevLink:hover, #prevLink:visited:hover { background: url(../images/prevlabel.gif) left 15% no-repeat; }
#nextLink:hover, #nextLink:visited:hover { background: url(../images/nextlabel.gif) right 15% no-repeat; }

#imageDataContainer{ font: 10px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; margin: 0 auto; line-height: 1.4em; overflow: auto; width: 100% ; }

#imageData{ padding:0 10px; color: #666; }
#imageData #imageDetails{ width: 70%; float: left; text-align: left; }  
#imageData #caption{ font-weight: bold; }
#imageData #numberDisplay{ display: block; clear: left; padding-bottom: 1.0em;  }
#imageData #bottomNavClose{ width: 66px; float: right;  padding-bottom: 0.7em; outline: none;}

#overlay{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 90; width: 100%; height: 500px; background-color: #000; }
```

But using it I get my pictures like this :

Pic1:

[image]

in other words - on the whole width of my page, I want to customise it in a way to get this result :

Pic2 :

[image]

I want to get 3-4 pics on each row, I tried by simply doing this:

```
<body  style="width: 500px;">
   <a href="pic/1.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]"><img src="pic/1.jpg" width="110" height="90" alt="image" /></a>
   <a href="pic/2.jpg" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]"><img src="pic/2.jpg" width="110" height="90" alt="image" /></a>
</body>
```

But this leads to a bug when I go to large view for a single picture...

Thanks

Leron

Comment: What's the html? You need to set a width to a div that contains your thumbnails. That width should be equal to 3 or 4 pics plus all applicable padding/margin values, you can actually determine width by eye and 'display ruler feature' of Web Developer plugin for FF.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it occurs that my images are too big, and that leads to the problem when try to view them in large mode.Styled `<div>` do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use responsive image gallery plugins which display your images, when they are clicked by resizing them according to the width and height of your screen. a good one would be shadowbox or yoxview.